# Регулярные выражения

Tags: objective-c

Здраствуйте.
У меня есть NSString *ParamString  -  в ней хранится запись вида firstparam/secondparam. Мне нужно вытащить в другие переменные firstparam и secondparam.То есть:

NSString *FirstParamString  = firstparam; // текст до слеша
NSString* SecondParamString  = secondparam; // текст после слеша

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Класс php совместимых регулярный выражений, с примером использования http://www.cyberforum.ru/objective-c/thread1207490.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этой задачи регуляки не обязательны, достаточно метода

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator;
```

Пример использования для вашей задачи:

```
NSString *paramsString = @"first/second";
NSArray *params = [paramsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *firstParam = [params objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *secondParam = [params objectAtIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Регулярное выражение здесь будет лишним я думаю.

В Objective C есть же **componentsSeparatedByString:**

```
NSString *ParamString= @"firstparam/secondparam";
NSArray *array = [ParamString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
```

Только результат будет возвращен в виде массива. Но потом можно каждой переменной присвоить по одному из элементов массива. Или может быть можно сразу как-то присвоить. Вам должно быть виднее. Я просто в глаза не разу не видел Objective C.

[Вот здесь](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) можете почитать про все доступные методы для класса NSString.